# Execution time of pi calculation in shell scripts

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting, time

I have to run a couple of command lines on a shell script on Ubuntu,
one of those is a pi calculation.

It works fine when i run it on terminal via the following cmd line:

```
time echo "scale=6500;4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

But when I run it on a script I get no luck. Typing in time before I execute the script i.e.

```
time ./filename.sh
```

isn't enough as I have to also run other commands in the script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Define “no luck”. In meantime see if [How to get execution time of a script effectively?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively) has anything useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your interactive shell is bash or zsh where `time` is a keyword.

And your script is a `sh` script (where `sh` is not based on `bash`, `ksh` nor `zsh`) where `time` is `/usr/bin/time` which would only `time` the `echo` command above.

Just do:

```
echo ... | "time" bc ...
```

as it's really `bc` you want to get the execution time of here.

Quoting `time` here makes sure it's not treated as a keyword in shells that have a `time` keyword.