# How to time the execution of parallel commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, time, parallelism

I am trying to write a bash script that launches n commands in the background and then waits for each command to finish. I can easily get the time it took to execute all the commands using `time sh myscript.sh`.
But I want to get the execution time for each command.

So lets say I have two commands and I launch them in my script like so:

```
echo "1" &
echo "2" &
wait
```

Now to time each command I have tried the following:

```
time echo "1" 1> /dev/null &
time echo "2" 1> /dev/null &
wait
```

But that seems to only print the overall time of the script (or something similar to it).

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: That should work and you should get two outputs of `time` when starting your script with `myscript.sh`. Test with `sleep 5s` and `sleep 10s` instead of `echo...`.

Comment: "that seems to only print the overall time" => Give us the output in your question, and tell us why you are not satisfied with it

Comment: You can use your own wrapper command for timing command execution -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334152/64411

Comment: @Thomas you are right. Sorry maybe I was looking at something weird. Thanks.